# Is there a way to report prevalence ratio using gtsummary?

Tags: r, gtsummary

How would I report PR instead of OR?

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(2022)

trial_data <- tibble(
  "outcome"  = factor(rbinom(1000, 1, 0.20),
                      labels = c("No", "Yes")),
  "var1" = factor(rbinom(1000, 2, 0.25),
                  labels = c("Low", "Middle", "High")),
  "var2" = factor(rbinom(1000, 2, 0.20),
                  labels = c("Primary", "Secondary", "Tertiary")),
  "var3" = factor(rbinom(1000, 1, 0.10),
                  labels = c("No", "Yes")),
  "var4" = round(rnorm(1000, 20, 5)),
)


trial_data %>% count(var3)

# Logistic regression with odds ratio

trial_data %>%
  tbl_uvregression(
                   method = glm,
                   y = "outcome",
                   method.args = list(family = binomial),
                   exponentiate = TRUE,
                   pvalue_fun = function(x) style_pvalue(x, digits = 2)
  )
```

Comment: The gtsummary regression functions accept custom tidiers. If you can write a function with the same inputs as `broom::tidy.glm()` AND the output is the same except the OR is replaced with the PR, you'll be all set.

Comment: Thanks. So we do not have a function at the moment that gives the PR instead of PR right?